# R: a tidy way to count number of rows between pipes?

Tags: r, tidyr

Using R and tidyr, I want to count the number of rows of a dataframe between two pipes; is there an elegant way to do this?

I ran into the problem when removing rows with only NA, then having to count the number of rows of the dataframe so far. Can I do this without storing the dataframe between the pipes?

Here is a **reproducible example**. I essentially need `XXX` to refer to the dataframe after `drop_na()`.

```
library(dplyr)

scrap <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:16, ncol = 4))
scrap[4,] <- rep(NA, 4)

scrap %>%
  drop_na() %>%
  mutate(index=c(1:nrow(XXX)))
```

I thought it would guess what I am doing if I do not refer to anything as below, but no.

```
scrap %>%
  drop_na() %>%
  mutate(index=c(1:nrow()))
```

> Error in nrow() : argument "x" is missing, with no default

Is there an elegant solution I am missing?

Comment: How about 1:n()？

Comment: if you just need the index, why not just use `row_number()`, like scrap %>%
  drop_na() %>%
  mutate(index=row_number())

Comment: Use a dot? E.g. `1:nrow(.)`

Comment: The dot is exactly what I was missing. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if I understood your question, but using `dplyr::row_number` :

```
library(dplyr)  
scrap %>%
  drop_na() %>%
  mutate(index=row_number())
```

Returns:

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4 index
1  1  5  9 13     1
2  2  6 10 14     2
3  3  7 11 15     3
```